# Including custom properties in default request tracking in application insights - node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights

I have an express app with application insights switched on in the azure portal. All the requests made to the server are being logged automatically, however the default configuration does not provide the level of detail I am after - I would like the user agent of the request to be exposed in the application insights logs. I can see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155252/user-agent-information-in-azure-application-insights) question that it is no longer available by default and I will have to do some configuration within my app.

My question is: Is it possible to make changes to the default configuration for tracking requests using the [node js application insights sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights) to add in custom properties (such as the user agent)?

And if so can this be a change do a default setting, or do I need to build a custom telemetry process?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. It can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a custom telemetry processor, since it's not supported to add custom properties in a default settings.